# How to (very) quickly refresh an image

Tags: android

I have an ImageView in my Android app that I want to change periodically with a variable frame rate. The only way I have managed to do that is by using the postDelayed function of a handler inside a run() function. This would have worked in theory, but in reality the maximum frame rate I could get was about 4-5 fps. I need a higher framerate (40 to 60 fps).

Can anybody please suggest a solution for refreshing an image faster than this (even if it isn't an imageView)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess, you need something like game loop. It can be done with SurfaceView. Check this tutorial http://obviam.net/index.php/a-very-basic-the-game-loop-for-android/

Comment: Yeah, I remember that. Thanks for the info, seems like the right choice, although even that way rendering a high-res bmp fast might not be possible.

Comment: Well, you can do optimizations like downscale, split bitmap, do clipping. Also you can use OpenGL.

Comment: The image I'm trying to refresh is supposed to be a high res image that takes up the whole screen. I tried changing it with a canvas as suggested, but I also get a pretty low framerate (which is also platform dependent). I'm going to try Cocos2DX (which might put more focus on the gpu), but if that won't work, then I guess there's no way to get high framerates from changing high-res images (short of making a movie).